# Selected items with check box should be printed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have an entry with child data and here is check button with child items. If I check the items, then selected item should be printed - not all child items of this parent. How to do that?

Comment: You have a problem, but this isnt it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option I can think of is to commit changes you've made (i.e. store checkbox values into the table).

Then call the report by passing the "master" row ID. Report's query would then look like this:

```
select some_columns
from master_table m join detail_table d on d.master_id = m.master_id
where m.master_id = :par_master_id
  and d.checkbox = 1
```

The `where` condition would make sure that only checked rows are printed.

In order to "reset" it, you could use the "After Report" trigger and

```
update detail_table set
  checkbox = 0
where master_id = :par_master_id
```

---

However, this won't work in multi-user environment as many users could work with same data and "overwrite" each other's checkboxes. Better option would be to create additional table and store [user, master_id, detail_id] rows so that everyone uses their own values.

Or, while in form, if there aren't too many child records, use a loop to concatenate IDs of checked rows and pass them to the report which would split that string into rows.